# C++ vector being overwritten

Tags: c++

I have I have objects with x, y, z coordinates and another parameter - energy. The energy of objects with the same x, y, z coordinates are to be summed up. I have seen a program how this can be implemented and followed the exact same approach, however, my program fails and I do not understand why.

Outlined is the approach.

I have a vector of the object of class D;

```
class D; //for the sake of time you will understand the structure of this class as u keep reading

int main()
 {
  vector< D>cont; //the objects to be summed are stored in this container
  vector< D>cont2; //Second container: you will see the need later on

  co_ord [100][100][100]; //Declare the range of available x, and z coordinates

  for (int z = -49; z<50; z++)
      for (int y = -49; y<50; y++)
          for (int x = -49; x<50; x++)
              co_ord[z][y][x] = -1;

 for (int i = 0; i < cont.size(); i++){
  int x, y, z, E;
 **//PROBLEM AREA!!!**
   x = cont[i].getx();//member function of class D : returns x of current obj
   y = cont[i].gety();
   z = cont[i].gez();
   E = cont[i].getE();
 if(x>=50){x = 49;}
 if(y>=50){y = 49;}
if(z>=50){z = 49;}

  if(x<= -50){x = -49;}
  if(y<= -50){y = -49;}
 if(z<= -50){z = -49;}

  if (co_ord[z][y][x] = -1)
  {
    D obj(x, y, z, E); //create new object of class D
    cont2.push_back(obj);
    int index = cont2.size();
    co_ord[z][y][x] = index - 1; // co_ord[z][y][x] has the storage index of this co-ordinate
  } 
 else {cont2[co_ord[z][y][x]].AddEn(E); //AddEn() is a member function of class D that adds energy to "this" obj;    
  return 0;
   }
}
```

}

Now I have 2 major problems:

1. If I use co_ord[300][300][300], the program gives a **segmentation fault**. A **cout** statement will execute if placed before the 3 consecutive for-loops, but not afterwards;
   When I reduce the dimension of co_ord to co_ord[100][100][100], that problem is solved and I will be able to cout a statement anywhere else.
2. However, there is another weird problem that I still have no idea of why that is. The area where this occurs is labeled "PROBLEM AREA" in the preceding code. Basically what happens is that co_ord[z][y][x] will give out some strange values after the first loop. The first loop runs well i.e co_ord[-9][0][1] will cout -1, but on the second loop, I have values like 6783 and other sometimes maybe up to an 8 digit number. But this is occurring during the second loop. I have tried everything I know but I am not succeeding.

   Please, can someone offer a clue on why I have the 2 above mentioned errors or the way around it? As I said, I have exactly a similar code running on my system which is part of a larger application. In the code, they implemented some memory allocation procedure for the container class they created, however their procedure is complex for me hence my decision to do it with the standard c++ library vector. Any help will be appreciated.

sorry for posting an erroneous code earlier, i have corrected most (I hope all) of the typos

Comment: Is there code omitted where you fill `cont` or `cont2`?

Comment: EH? negative index into an array (-9)? what the heck? is there something that I've missed? May be you should start off with printing out the locations of all `D` objects and looking carefully at the indexes!

Comment: You should really fix you example code and produce atleast a compilable example - else we're going to be sitting here all day highlighting really basic mistakes (unless that is what you want)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If I use co_ord[300][300][300], the
>   program gives a segmentation fault.

This is normal. Let's say you have `int a[2]`; it's an array of two elements, starting from zero (`a[0]`, `a[1]`). `a[2]` would be the third element and accessing it results into undefined behavior.

> co_ord[-9][0][1] will cout -1, but on the second loop, I have values like 6783

Similar problem as above. If you have `a[10]` you can access it through `a[n]` with n having [0, 9] range. Accessing it with a negative value is undefined behavior.

```
for (int i = 0; i < cont.size(); i++)
    int x, y, z, E;
```

This is a no-op since the for doesn't have brackets (good indentation habits, which you don't seem to have, would have made the error obvious). Since you then use the variables - which will be out of scope - I have no idea how your program compiles successfully. Besides that, you also have a line with `co_ord[300][300][300]` without the type, which also shouldn't compile.

Comment: Thank you all for commenting, I learnt quite something from your comments and will make adjustment to the code. There is a bracket in the for-loop, but I mistakenly omitted it while posting. Thanks for ur comment.

Comment: Sorry about my initial post which must be somewhat confusing. I have changed a couple of things in the code so that the x , y and z starts from positive values and the program is running. I.e the new code looks like this                                               for (int z = -49; z<50; z++) 
      for (int y = 0; y<100; y++)
          for (int x = 0; x<100; x++) 
              co_ord[z][y][x] = -1;
I set any x, y or z of the object > 99 to 99 and any < 0 to 0 and the code works fine. H/v, if I try chaning the size of the array to co_ord[300][300][300], then I get the segmentation fault.

Answer (score 4):

> 1. If I use co_ord[300][300][300], the program gives a segmentation fault.

Of course. Your code declares this array as ranging from 0–299 (inclusive) on all three dimensions.

Now, from your code:

> ```
> if (co_ord[z][y][x] = -1)
> ```

Notice `=` instead of `==`. You are assigning, not comparing.

Comment: Thanks, it is a == in the original code. I made quite some error while typing and editing it in here. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 3):

You missed the brackets on for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < cont.size(); i++)
{
...
}
```

Comment: that's not the problem, it's just a typo, without them it won't compile (you cant have a single declaration as a body of a for loop). Also, there is an end-brace in there, so they'd even be unbalanced.

Answer (score 0):

Also a typo?

```
cont2.push_back(ob);
```

shouldn't it be:

```
cont2.push_back(obj);
```